# Checking if GPS is enabled in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

I am working on a project containing google maps. When the activity loads I want to check whether GPS is enabled or not. So I used the following code to redirect to the page containing settings.

```
if(!manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ))
        {
             AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
        }
```

But the problem is that if I enable GPS and come back to the app I want the page to load again so that the map loads. How do I ensure that my activity runs again?

Comment: you should automatically enable melodramatically the gps then start activity

Comment: it's not prudent to enable without asking user

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the methods `onResume`.

If you know the activity lifecycle, you see that your activity is paused (`onPause`) when you go to activate your GPS, and `onResume` will be called when you return to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Put android:noHistory="true" in the manifest file of the present class.It will not leave any traces. Cleanup the stack.